# How do I use Ubuntu Backup (DejaDup) with Owncloud (WebDAV)?

Tags: backup, webdav

I'm trying to use Ubuntu Backup (ie. DejaDup) with [Owncloud](http://www.owncloud.org). I have an account with [Owncube](http://www.owncube.org) and made a folder in my root called 'backup-computer1' where I want my backups to go.

Under Settings in Owncloud, it says

*WebDAV: https://owncube.com/files/webdav.php*

Then I went to Ubuntu settings, Backup, the Storage tab, and selected **WebDAV** from the dropdown list, and entered the following settings:

- Server: owncube.com/files/webdav.php
- **tick** "Use secure connection (HTTPS)"
- Port: 443
- Folder: /backup-computer1
- Username: myowncubeusername

but it keeps telling me it can't find the hostname. When I entered the full webdav address (https://owncube.com/files/webdav.php) it just removed it from the form. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For Owncloud 6 & 7 the above path did not work, the folder needs to be: /<owncloud prefix>/remote.php/files/<backup folder>

Comment: owncloud.com *is* the server address (or domain name, to be more accurate, which is translated into a server address by a DNS lookup). There is not such thing as a 'long' server address. The first part of a URL speifies the protocol (https), then comes the server address (owncloud.com). The rest of the URL is passed to the server to handle as it sees fit (usually by returning a file or running a program and returning the output).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out :-)

These are the correct settings:

- Server: owncube.com
- **tick** "Use secure connection (HTTPS)"
- Port: 443
- Folder: /files/webdav.php/backup-computer1
- Username: myowncubeusername

I guess the dejadup form isn't smart enough to parse the "long" server address, so the rest has to be part of the "folder" field.

Comment: This does not work for me. I am using a local install of owncloud using an IP address without https. I still get HTTP Error: Could not connect: Connection refused

Comment: OK if someone else finds this (nextcloud): server address: 192.168.1.11 Untick https if not configured port empty folder /remote.php/webdav/files username: yourNextcloudUserName . It will then prompt you to username password. Sadly after that I still get *Not a WebDAV-enabled share* I don't know how to fix that yet.