# Backups (Deja Dup) is missing Nextcloud option in 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, deja-dup, nextcloud

My Déjà Dup is missing an option to back up to Nextcloud. This is on 20.04 LTS. I see only three: Google Drive, Network Server, and Local Folder. Is there some way I can add it back?

I *do* see the Nextcloud option on a different computer running 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whew, that took some digging. The Déjà Dup team says that, as of 39.0, "Nextcloud accounts will now appear as webdav network server accounts." So the new way to use a Nextcloud storage location is to select "Network Server" and type in a URI using a `dav` or `davs` scheme.

For example: `davs://example.com/remote.php/dav/files/USERNAME/` . Then it'll ask for the usual inputs: username (yes, even though it is in the URI), password, and encryption preference.

You can see a nearly correct URI in the Files app:

[image: screen grab of Nextcloud Files app settings showing webdav URL]

You can copy that URI and change the scheme to `davs` (or `dav`) to create a URI that will work in Deja Dup.

See also:

- https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/deja-dup/-/blob/debian/master/NEWS.md#anchor-390
- https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/19/user_manual/files/access_webdav.html#nextcloud-desktop-and-mobile-clients
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249942
- and maybe also [How do I use Ubuntu Backup (DejaDup) with Owncloud (WebDAV)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128636/how-do-i-use-ubuntu-backup-dejadup-with-owncloud-webdav)